# How does Meteor Up work?

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

I recently created a droplet on Digital Ocean, and then just used [Meteor Up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) to deploy my site to it.

As awesome as it was to not have to mess with all of the details, I'm feeling a little worried and out of the loop about what's happening with my server.

For example, I was using the console management that Digital Ocean provides, and I tried to use the `meteor mongo` command to investigate what was happening with my database. It just errored, with `command not found: meteor`.

I know my database works, since records are persistent across accesses, but it seems like Meteor Up accomplished this without retaining any of the testing and development interfaces I grew used to on my own machine.

**What does it do???** And how can I get a closer look at things going on behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1):

Meteor Up installs your application to the remote server, but does not install the global meteor command-line utilities.

For those, simply run `curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh`.

Comment: That's helpful, but I'd also like more details about what "installs your application to the remote server" really means. Describing them or pointing in the direction of a resource that can describe them would be appreciated :)

Comment: @blaineh: See their docs.  https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up#server-setup-details

Answer (score 0):

MUP does a few things. Note that this MUP is currently under active development and some of this process will likely change soon. The new version will manage deployment via Docker, add support for `meteor build` options, and other cool stuff. Notes on the development version (`mupx`) can be found here: https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/tree/mupx.

`mup setup` installs (depending on your `mup.json` file) Node, PhantomJS, MongoDB, and stud (for SSL support). It also installs the shell script to setup your environment variables, as well as your upstart configuration file.

`mup deploy` runs `meteor build` on your local machine to [package your meteor app as a bundled and zipped node app for deployment](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/deploying). It then copies the packaged app to the remote server, unbundles it, installs npm modules, and runs as a node app.

Note that `meteor build` packages your app in production mode rather than the debug mode that runs by default on `localhost` when you call `meteor` or `meteor run`. The next version of MUP will have a `buildOptions` property in `mup.json` that you can use to set the `debug` and `mobileSettings` options when you deploy.

Also, since your app is running directly via Node (rather than Meteor), `meteor mongo` won't work. Instead, you need to ssh into the remote server and call `mongo appName`.

From there, @SLaks is right about how it sets things up on the server (from https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up#server-setup-details):

This is how Meteor Up will configure the server for you based on the given `appName` or using "meteor" as default appName. This information will help you customize the server for your needs.

- your app lives at `/opt/<appName>/app`
- mup uses `upstart` with a config file at `/etc/init/<appName>.conf`
- you can start and stop the app with upstart: `start <appName>` and `stop <appName>`
- logs are located at: `/var/log/upstart/<appName>.log`
- MongoDB installed and bound to the local interface (cannot access from the outside)
- the database is named `<appName>`